# android , read jpg image from assets

Tags: android

I load images from assets folder, but I have one problem.

The same image loaded from assets and resource are not same dimensions - resolution.

For getting image from assets I use this method:

```
AssetManager am=this.getAssets();
            try {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(am.open("imgs/a.jpg"));
                imageViewDraw.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Output for the same image loaded from R.drawable and assets are on images

Can some one tell me why and how can I read image from assets, but resolution should be the same as from R.drawable ?

[image: output images]

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that Android doesn't scale the image from drawable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the bitmap to an Imageview use the scaleType and adjustViewbounds parameters. So for example in XML:

```
                        <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
```

The thing is that when you load images from the assets directory the system doesn't apply any scaling or processiong whatsoever to your bitmaps, instead when using the drawable folder, android tries to scale your image according to your device's resolution.

So the only real way to have the exact same result is to use a fixed size for the imageview, ideally you should specify it in dps and ideally you should put that value on a dimens.xml file so you can change that value for various system configurations

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setDrawable instead with a scaled drawable.

imageView.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getContext().getResources(),bitmap));

This is also why the other method that does not get the getResources() parameter is deprecated, it will take care of the scalings in this case.